# Salesforce returns Unknown Error while trying to insert using REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, salesforce

My project is interacting with SalesForce and I am able to retrieve data from salesforce.But when I tried to POST JSON back to Salesforce for creating new record, I am getting a response as "UNKNOWN ERROR". We are consuming the [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications) API of Salesforce.
There is no error and I am getting a response.

```
HttpClient createClient = new HttpClient();
string requestMessage = JSON;
HttpContent createContent = new StringContent(requestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
string uri = serviceUrl + "/services/apexrest/MYTool/v1/";
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + oauthToken);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Content = createContent;
HttpResponseMessage message1 = await createClient.SendAsync(request);
string responseString1 = await message1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I am using .NET 4.5 and C#. Please let me know if any details required.
Any help will be very much thankful.

Comment: Curiosity, why you have `oauthToken + 1` ?

Comment: Sorry its a mistake. I just tried to get authentication error . I will update this ..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Salesforce's REST API try to use a wrapper client library, like [SalesforceSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/SalesforceSharp).

SalesforceSharp supports many operations on Salesforce REST API, like POST:

```
client.Create("YourRecordEntityName", 
   new { Name = "name created", Description = "description created" }));
```